# Prevent custom tool from running when I save a file

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio has a feature called [Custom Tools](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31257/Custom-Tools-Explained). The Custom Tool will run every time I save a file or, if I click the "Run Custom Tool" menu item. Is there a way to make it run *only* when I click the Run Custom Tool menu item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to discriminate from within the custom tool code. This may be stating the obvious, but it sounds like a normal VS add-in would be more appropriate in your case.